# Dom append child y nodos

Tags: javascript, dom

he tenido un problema y es que quiero tratar de crear una app que pueda agregar y eliminar inputs, que cuando no halla inputs salte un alert para que agreguen mas, cuando halla un solo alert, de un mensaje de confirmación en la pantalla, y en caso de ser "si", lo elimine y en caso de ser "no", lo anule.
el problema esta en que al crear mas de un input y eliminar todos hasta que quede solo uno, ese ultimo nunca se eliminara, saltando un error.

```js
var caja = document.getElementById("caja");
var input;
var boton = document.getElementById("btn");
var borrar = document.getElementById("btn2");
var guardar = document.getElementById("btn3");

function crearinput(){
 input = document.createElement("input");
 input.setAttribute("type", "text");
 input.setAttribute("id", "input");
 caja.appendChild(input);
}




function removerinput(event){
 
 if (caja.childElementCount <= 0){
  alert("porfavor agrega uno o mas elementos")
 }
 else if (caja.childElementCount > 1){
  input = document.getElementById("input");
  caja.removeChild(input);
 }
 else if (caja.childElementCount === 1 ){
  var alerta = confirm("Estas a punto de eliminar tu ultimo elemento ¿Estas  seguro?");
   if (alerta == true){
   caja.removeChild(input);
   alert("Formato limpio");
   }
 }
 
}


function guardar(){
 localStorage.setAttribute("valores", input)
}

boton.addEventListener("click", crearinput);
borrar.addEventListener("click", removerinput);
guardar.addEventListener("click", guardar);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lagranestafa.css">
<html>
<head>
 <title>LaGranEstafa</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <div id="caja">
 </div>
   <br>
   <input type="button" name="" id="btn" value="Agregar Valor">
   <input type="button" name="" id="btn2" value="Remover Valor">
   <input type="button" name="" id="btn3" value="Guardar">
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lagranestafa.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenido de nuevo jhonathan, supongo esta es la otra pregunta. Bueno, el error es bastante simple pero a todos les puede pasar.

dentro del primer elseif que hiciste tienes esta linea:

```
input = document.getElementById("input");
```

Simplemente llévalo al principio de tu función para que input tenga un valor en todos los casos ya que si no llegara a cumplir el primer elseif nunca se le asignaría su valor.

quedaria asi:

```
function removerinput(event){
    input = document.getElementById("input"); // <===aquí tiene que estar===

    if (caja.childElementCount <= 0){
        alert("porfavor agrega uno o mas elementos")
    }
    else if (caja.childElementCount > 1){
        // aqui estaba el input...
        caja.removeChild(input);
    }
    else if (caja.childElementCount === 1 ){
        var alerta = confirm("Estas a punto de eliminar tu ultimo elemento ¿Estas  seguro?");
        if (alerta == true){
            caja.removeChild(input);
            alert("Formato limpio");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: miles de gracias, no me había fijado de verdad gracias de corazon

Comment: Si es así podés dar la pregunta como respondida...